# how to redirect from a form to different page?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post, get

I would like to add a form in my page. When I click on the submit button it post some details.

```
<form action="http://toggletime.net/redirect.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="url" />
<button type="submit">Search</button></form>
```

I can use `GET` or `POST`. But my problem is I want to create diffrent page for each `POST` or `GET`.

The actual URL will be like: `http://toggletime.net/redirect.php?url=text`
I want to redirect it to: `http://toggletime.net/text`

How can I do that?

Comment: use htaccess for achieving this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `redirect.php` do this:

```
if (isset($_GET['url']) && !empty($_GET['url'])) {
    header("Location: {$_GET['url']}");
    exit;
}
```

Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Just about to post an almost identical solution. I'm guessing this is exactly what OP wants.

Comment: Nice +1. It should be noted that when redirecting you probably want to send the appropriate redirect status code. [Here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is a list of the w3.org status codes. You may possibly want to look into the ***303 See Other*** code...

Comment: but here my problem in no such page is that page in not found.

Comment: but here my problem in no such page like that. The page is not found.

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

how can i create page dynamically during each search? or is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

but here my problem in no such page like that. The page is not found.

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

how can i create page dynamically during each search?
or is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: You can't create pages dynamically. But if you use Apache you can use URL rewrites[1] to rewrite http://toggletime.net/text to http://toggletime.net/page.php?text=text which will appear functionally the same to the user. [1] http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/